# xsl transformation to sort output at the end of traversal

Tags: xslt

what is the actual best way to transform this

```
<root>
  <data/>
  <data/>
</root>
```

into this:

```
<data1/>
<data1/>
<data2/>
<data2/>
```

Somehow the way xslt engine works let me think it can only produce this:

```
<data1/>
<data2/>
<data1/>
<data2/>
```

which is produced by this simple sheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:element name="data1"/>
    <xsl:element name="data2"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is it possible to do some kind of reordering at the end of transformation (without using a second application) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use two separate templates to create the `data1` and `data2` elements. Then you can apply these templates from a template matching the root node, for example. The `mode` attribute of `xsl:template` is also useful in this case:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//data" mode="data1"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//data" mode="data2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data" mode="data1">
    <xsl:element name="data1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data" mode="data2">
    <xsl:element name="data2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to add elements like in your example stylesheet but in different order you can do it somewhat like this.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- adding  data1 for every data tag-->
  <xsl:for-each select="//data" >
    <xsl:element name="data1"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <!-- adding  data2 for every data tag-->
  <xsl:for-each select="//data" >
    <xsl:element name="data2"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: ok, I see, thanks. Though I prefer the recursive approach given by nwellnhof.